# QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka color format

Tags: colors, yuv

all

Does anybody know details about  **QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka** format, it's the output format of qcom 7x30 h/w decoder, how data is stored in such color format? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my research on this, about **QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka converting to YUV420Planar (I420)**. As far as `QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka` format is concerned, you can refer to `($your_android_native_sdk_dir)/WORKING_DIRECTORY/hardware/qcom/media/mm-core/inc/QOMX_IVCommonExtensions.h` source code. This function might idealy support generic resolution, however I only test on CIF size because unavailable given source input. Sure you can fake other size data as given input. Hope it is helpful if you are working on this.
I have saw the color is correct per my CIF test. The code is so long about 390 lines, so heavy. Including steps: construct yTileToMb, uvTileToMb, then converting y and u/v as followed.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
* Enumeration defining the extended uncompressed image/video
* formats.
*
* ENUMS:
*  YVU420PackedSemiPlanar       : Buffer containing all Y, and then V and U 
*                                 interleaved.
*  YVU420PackedSemiPlanar32m4ka : YUV planar format, similar to the 
*                                 YVU420PackedSemiPlanar format, but with the
*                                 following restrictions:
*
*                                 1. The width and height of both plane must 
*                                 be a multiple of 32 texels.
*
*                                 2. The base address of both planes must be 
*                                 aligned to a 4kB boundary.
* 
*  YUV420PackedSemiPlanar16m2ka : YUV planar format, similar to the
*                                 YUV420PackedSemiPlanar format, but with the
*                                 following restrictions:
*
*                                 1. The width of the luma plane must be a
*                                 multiple of 16 pixels.
*
*                                 2. The address of both planes must be 
*                                 aligned to a 2kB boundary.
* 
*  YUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka : YUV planar format, similar to the 
*                                 YUV420PackedSemiPlanar format, but with the
*                                 following restrictions:
*
*                                 1. The data is laid out in a 4x2 MB tiling 
*                                 memory structure
*
*                                 2. The width of each plane is a multiple of
*                                 2 4x2 MB tiles.
*
*                                 3. The height of each plan is a multiple of
*                                 a 4x2 MB tile.
*
*                                 4. The base address of both planes must be 
*                                 aligned to an 8kB boundary.
*
*                                 5. The tiles are scanned in the order 
*                                 defined in the MFCV5.1 User's Manual.
*
*                                                                       i.e, CIF size in pysical location
*
*                                                                       Luma order(4x2 MB = 64x32 pix): 54 tiles:
*                                                                       0  1  6  7  8  9
*                                                                       2  3  4  5  10 11
*                                                                       12 13 18 19 20 21
*                                                                       14 15 16 17 22 23
*                                                                       24 25 30 31 32 33
*                                                                       26 27 28 29 34 35
*                                                                       36 37 42 43 44 45
*                                                                       38 39 40 41 46 47
*                                                                       48 49 50 51 52 53
*                                                                       MBs in a y tile:
*                                                                       0  1  2  3
*                                                                       22 23 24 25
*                                                                       Chromas order(64x32 pix):
*                                                                       0  1  6  7  8  9
*                                                                       2  3  4  5  10 11
*                                                                       12 13 18 19 20 21
*                                                                       14 15 16 17 22 23
*                                                                       24 25 26 27 28 29
*                                                                       MBs in a uv tile:
*                                                                       0  1  2  3
*                                                                       22 23 24 25
*                                                                       44 45 46 47
*                                                                       66 67 68 69
*
*/

// YUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka,    // 12 bit, yyyyyyyy vuvu
// YUV420Planar, 12 bit, yyyyyyyy uu vv
#pragma pack(1)
typedef enum {
    Scan_Init       = 0,
    Scan_Hor,
    Scan_VerDown,
    Scan_VerUp
} ScanMode;
typedef struct{
    uint16_t    startMbIndex;
    uint8_t     numMBs;
//  bool        lastTileInHor;
    bool        lastTileInVer;
} MbGroup;
#pragma pack()

#define ALIGN_B(x,a)        (((x)+(a)-1) &(~((a)-1)))
#define MAX_RESOLUTION_X    1920    // 4096
#define MAX_RESOLUTION_Y    1088    // 3072
#define MAX_TILES_NUM       (((MAX_RESOLUTION_X+63)>>6) * ((MAX_RESOLUTION_Y+31)>>5))

int32_t ToI420::YUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8kaToYUV420Planar( uint8_t* src, uint8_t* dst_y, uint8_t* dst_u, uint8_t* dst_v,
            const int32_t width, const int32_t height,
            const int32_t stride_y, const int32_t stride_u, const int32_t stride_v )
{
    const int32_t srcStrideY    = ALIGN_B( width, 128 );
    const int32_t srcHeightY    = ALIGN_B( height, 32 );
    const int32_t srcStrideUV   = srcStrideY;   // v/u interlaced
    const int32_t srcHeightUV   = ALIGN_B( (height>>1), 32 );
    const int32_t srcSizeY      = ALIGN_B( (srcStrideY * srcHeightY), 8192 );
    const int32_t srcSizeUV     = ALIGN_B( (srcStrideUV * srcHeightUV), 8192 );
    uint8_t* src_y              = src;
    uint8_t* src_uv             = src_y + srcSizeY;

    const int32_t wTiles        = (width+63)>>6;
    const int32_t hTilesY       = (height+31)>>5;
    const int32_t hTilesUV      = (height/2+31)>>5;
    const int32_t numTilesY     = wTiles*hTilesY;
    const int32_t numTilesUV    = wTiles*hTilesUV; 
    const int32_t wMacroblocks  = (width+15)>>4;
    const int32_t hMacroblocks  = (height+15)>>4;
    int32_t numMbInTile         = 4*2;  // y: 4*2; uv: 4*4
    const int32_t mbOffsetTileHor       = 4;
    int32_t mbOffsetTileVer             = (wMacroblocks<<1);    // y: (wMacroblocks<<1); uv: (wMacroblocks<<2)  
    MbGroup yTileToMb[MAX_TILES_NUM]    = {0};  // each Tile index storing according MB index
    MbGroup uvTileToMb[MAX_TILES_NUM]   = {0};  // each Tile index storing according MB index
    assert( numTilesY <= MAX_TILES_NUM && numTilesUV <= MAX_TILES_NUM );
    int32_t availableTilesY             = numTilesY;
    int32_t availableTilesUV            = numTilesUV;
    const int32_t numTilesYPerScanUnit  = (wTiles<<1);
    int32_t tileIndex                   = 0;
    ScanMode preMode                    = Scan_Init;
    ScanMode curMode                    = Scan_Hor;
    int32_t scanedTiles                 = 0;
    int32_t hMbMultiple                 = 0;
    int32_t cntScanTimesInPeriod        = 0;    // maximal scan times is up to 4
    int32_t cnt1stLineTiles             = 0;
    int32_t cnt2ndLineTiles             = 0;
    uint16_t mbPosition                 = 0;
    uint16_t lastMbIdx                  = mbPosition;
    uint16_t firstMbIdxUnit             = mbPosition;
    bool noEnoughMbInTile               = false;    

    // construct yTileToMb table
    while( availableTilesY > 0 ){       
        if ( availableTilesY >= numTilesYPerScanUnit ){         
            preMode                 = Scan_Init;
            curMode                 = Scan_Hor;
            lastMbIdx               = mbPosition;
            firstMbIdxUnit          = mbPosition;
            cntScanTimesInPeriod    = 0;    // maximal scan times is up to 4
            cnt1stLineTiles         = 0;
            cnt2ndLineTiles         = 0;
            noEnoughMbInTile        = false;
            scanedTiles             = 0;

            while ( scanedTiles < numTilesYPerScanUnit ){               
                if ( (tileIndex & 3) == 0 ){
                    firstMbIdxUnit = mbPosition;
                }
                noEnoughMbInTile = false;
                if ( curMode == Scan_Hor ){
                    if ( (preMode == Scan_VerUp && cnt1stLineTiles+1>= wTiles) || 
                         (preMode == Scan_VerDown && cnt2ndLineTiles+1>= wTiles) ){
                             noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                           yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor = true;
                    }
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex   = mbPosition;
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs         = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<1) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;                   
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    if ( noEnoughMbInTile && cntScanTimesInPeriod  == 1){
                        if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }
                    }else if ( cntScanTimesInPeriod == 2 ){
                        if ( preMode == Scan_Init || preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }
                    }else if ( cntScanTimesInPeriod == 4 ){                     
                        if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if ( preMode == Scan_Init ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                        }
                        if ( cnt2ndLineTiles >= wTiles && preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;                           
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( cnt1stLineTiles >= wTiles && preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;                         
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else{
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }
                    }
                }else if ( curMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                    if ( cnt1stLineTiles+1 >= wTiles ){
                        noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                      yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor  = true;
                    }
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex= mbPosition;
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs     = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<1) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;
                    mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                    preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                    curMode = Scan_Hor;
                }else if ( curMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                    if ( cnt2ndLineTiles+1 >= wTiles ){
                        noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                      yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor  = true;
                    }
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex= mbPosition;
                    yTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs     = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<1) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;
                    mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                    preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                    curMode = Scan_Hor;
                }
                cntScanTimesInPeriod &= 0x03;
                ++ scanedTiles;
            }
            mbPosition = lastMbIdx + (mbOffsetTileVer<<1);
            availableTilesY -= numTilesYPerScanUnit;
        }else{
            scanedTiles = 0;
            hMbMultiple = hMacroblocks - (tileIndex/wTiles)*2;
            noEnoughMbInTile = false;
            while ( scanedTiles < wTiles ){
                yTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex = mbPosition;
                yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInVer= true;
                if ( scanedTiles+1 == wTiles ){
                    noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                  yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor  = true;
                }
                yTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))*hMbMultiple) : (4*hMbMultiple);
                ++ tileIndex;
                mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                ++ scanedTiles;
            }
            availableTilesY -= wTiles;
        }
    }

    numMbInTile = 4*4;  
    mbOffsetTileVer = (wMacroblocks<<2);
    mbPosition = 0;
    tileIndex = 0;
    // construct uvTileToMb table
    while( availableTilesUV > 0 ){      
        if ( availableTilesUV >= numTilesYPerScanUnit ){            
            preMode             = Scan_Init;
            curMode             = Scan_Hor;
            lastMbIdx           = mbPosition;
            firstMbIdxUnit      = mbPosition;
            cntScanTimesInPeriod= 0;    // maximal scan times is up to 4
            cnt1stLineTiles     = 0;
            cnt2ndLineTiles     = 0;
            noEnoughMbInTile    = false;
            scanedTiles         = 0;

            while ( scanedTiles < numTilesYPerScanUnit ){               
                if ( (tileIndex & 3) == 0 ){
                    firstMbIdxUnit = mbPosition;
                }
                noEnoughMbInTile = false;
                if ( curMode == Scan_Hor ){
                    if ( (preMode == Scan_VerUp && cnt1stLineTiles+1>= wTiles) || 
                         (preMode == Scan_VerDown && cnt2ndLineTiles+1>= wTiles) ){
                             noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                           uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor    = true;
                    }
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex  = mbPosition;
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs        = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<2) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;                   
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    if ( noEnoughMbInTile && cntScanTimesInPeriod  == 1){
                        if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }
                    }else if ( cntScanTimesInPeriod == 2 ){
                        if ( preMode == Scan_Init || preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }
                    }else if ( cntScanTimesInPeriod == 4 ){                     
                        if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if ( preMode == Scan_Init ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                        }else if ( preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                        }
                        if ( cnt2ndLineTiles >= wTiles && preMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerUp;                           
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit - mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else if ( cnt1stLineTiles >= wTiles && preMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                            preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                            curMode = Scan_VerDown;                         
                            mbPosition = firstMbIdxUnit + mbOffsetTileVer;
                        }else{
                            mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                        }
                    }
                }else if ( curMode == Scan_VerUp ){
                    if ( cnt1stLineTiles+1 >= wTiles ){
                        noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                      uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor = true;
                    }
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex  = mbPosition;
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs        = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<2) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;
                    mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    ++ cnt1stLineTiles;
                    preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                    curMode = Scan_Hor;
                }else if ( curMode == Scan_VerDown ){
                    if ( cnt2ndLineTiles+1 >= wTiles ){
                        noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                      uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor = true;
                    }
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex  = mbPosition;
                    uvTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs        = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))<<2) : numMbInTile;
                    ++ tileIndex;
                    mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                    ++ cntScanTimesInPeriod;
                    ++ cnt2ndLineTiles;
                    preMode = curMode;  // scan mode change need upate preMode
                    curMode = Scan_Hor;
                }
                cntScanTimesInPeriod &= 0x03;
                ++ scanedTiles;
            }
            mbPosition = lastMbIdx + (mbOffsetTileVer<<1);
            availableTilesUV -= numTilesYPerScanUnit;
        }else{
            scanedTiles = 0;
            hMbMultiple = hMacroblocks - (tileIndex/wTiles)*4;
            noEnoughMbInTile = false;
            while ( scanedTiles < wTiles ){
                uvTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex = mbPosition;
                uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInVer = true;
                if ( scanedTiles+1 == wTiles ){
                    noEnoughMbInTile = (ALIGN_B(width, 16) < srcStrideY);
//                  uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInHor = true;
                }
                uvTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs    = noEnoughMbInTile ? ((4-((srcStrideY-ALIGN_B(width,16))>>4))*hMbMultiple) : (4*hMbMultiple);
                ++ tileIndex;
                mbPosition += mbOffsetTileHor;
                ++ scanedTiles;
            }
            availableTilesUV -= wTiles;
        }
    }

    uint8_t* py     = src_y;    
    tileIndex = 0;
    // converting luma componet with yTileToMb
    while ( tileIndex < numTilesY ){
        uint16_t startMbIndex = yTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex;
        const int32_t startMbX = (startMbIndex % wMacroblocks);
        const int32_t startMbY = (startMbIndex / wMacroblocks);

        int32_t mb_x = startMbX;
        int32_t mb_y = startMbY;
        const int32_t cntMbLines = yTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInVer ? (hMacroblocks - (tileIndex/wTiles)*2) : 2;      
        const int32_t numMbPerLine = yTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs / cntMbLines;
        const int32_t sizePixelLine = (numMbPerLine << 4);
        int32_t mbLine = 0;
        while ( mbLine < cntMbLines ){
            assert( mb_y < hMacroblocks && mb_x < wMacroblocks );
            const int32_t dstOffsetY = (mb_y * stride_y + mb_x)<<4;
            int32_t _l = 0;
            // luma
            while( _l < 16 ){
                memcpy( dst_y + dstOffsetY + _l * stride_y, py, sizePixelLine );
                py += 64; // eliminate padding (64-sizePixelLine)
                ++ _l;
            }
            mb_x = startMbX;
            ++ mb_y;
            ++ mbLine;
        }       
        ++ tileIndex;
    }

    uint8_t* puv    = src_uv;
    tileIndex = 0;
    // convering cb/cr componets with uvTileToMb
    while ( tileIndex < numTilesUV ){
        uint16_t startMbIndex = uvTileToMb[tileIndex].startMbIndex;
        const int32_t startMbX = (startMbIndex % wMacroblocks);
        const int32_t startMbY = (startMbIndex / wMacroblocks);

        int32_t mb_x = startMbX;
        int32_t mb_y = startMbY;
        const int32_t cntMbLines = uvTileToMb[tileIndex].lastTileInVer ? (hMacroblocks - (tileIndex/wTiles)*4) : 4;
        const int32_t numMbPerLine = uvTileToMb[tileIndex].numMBs / cntMbLines;     
        int32_t mbLine = 0;
        while ( mbLine < cntMbLines ){
            assert( mb_y < hMacroblocks && mb_x < wMacroblocks );           
            // cb/cr
            int32_t mbIndex = 0;
            while ( mbIndex < numMbPerLine ){
                assert( mb_y < hMacroblocks && mb_x < wMacroblocks );
                const int32_t dstOffsetUV = (mb_y * stride_u + mb_x)<<3;            
                int32_t _l = 0;
                while( _l < 8 ){
                    const int32_t _offset = dstOffsetUV + _l * stride_u;
                    uint8_t* _u = dst_u + _offset;
                    uint8_t* _v = dst_v + _offset;
                    uint8_t* _src_vu = puv+(mbIndex<<4)+(_l<<6);
                    int32_t _interlace = 0;
                    for ( int32_t ichroma = 0; ichroma < 8; ++ichroma ){
                        _u[ichroma] = _src_vu[_interlace++];
                        _v[ichroma] = _src_vu[_interlace++];
                    }
                    ++ _l;
                }
                ++ mb_x;
                ++ mbIndex;
            }
            puv += 64*8;
            mb_x = startMbX;
            ++ mb_y;
            ++ mbLine;
        }
        if ( cntMbLines < 4 ){
            puv += 64*(4-cntMbLines)*8;
        }
        ++ tileIndex;
    }

    return 0;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Comment: This function is buggy. I'm decoding 720p and it crashes in the last loop that interleaves uv tiles (line `_v[ichroma] = _src_vu[_interlace++];` crashes). By the way, uv are interleaved, not interlaced, wrong wording is just confusing.

Comment: It almost does the job. When I added manual checks in the last loop to prevent invalid memory access (`if(_u + 8 <= dst_u + width * height / 4){ ... }`) then it stopped crashing, as expected last 16 rows of pixels of the decoded image are not correct. Some of them look like wrong tiles were placed in wrong places, others looks like black squares (where nothing was decoded to these tiles).

Comment: It looks like the last row of UV-tiles are still decoded in this zig-zag order, while they are actually positioned one after another, just like the comment before the function mentiones layout of the last UV row of tiles.

Comment: @Pavel, thanks for your comment. We do need take an eye on picture/tile boundary exactly, and just as my declaration it maybe not support other size and it was only tested with CIF size. So about other size conversion, it can not ensure its correctness, however at least the basic procedure logic is there. So have you any update about other resolution size support? I almost can not figure out about difference between interleave and interlace, "int _interlace = 0;" just a variable, right?

Comment: For 720p (1280 x 720 pix = 80 x 45 mb) size last row of UV-tiles, you are ture about its layout.

Comment: @Denbian interlaced means totally different stuff in video. Interleaved means uvuvuv. Interlaced means one picture contains even, another picture contains odd lines or something like that. In any case, your code is very helpful to understand the logic, I'll need to write my code anyways and your sample was most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Pavel, any update about for other video size compatible fix? maybe for general size? Now I will turn to other sizes, i.e, qcif, qvga, vga, 720p etc.

Comment: I have finished such implementation for general size (i.e,qcif, cif, qvga, vga, etc..). Removing such ugly state-machine actions, and using controllable zig, inverse-zig and to generate generate TilesTypeMap ahead instead. Well.

Comment: While the comments seem to have ended with people having some working code, for reference, some of the original qualcomm code that handles this format is available at https://gitorious.org/atrix-aosp/frameworks_base/source/8f901240ab7c98ad48542b99342d02ed84937395:media/libstagefright/colorconversion/ColorConverter.cpp. There's also well tested code (by Rafaël), which I think originally was based on the qualcomm code, at http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=modules/codec/omxil/qcom.c.

Answer (score 4):

Like the name suggests, the data is packed into 64x32 pixels "tiles".

You don't need to know the pixel format if you write the decoded picture into a compatible hardware surface.

I have reverse engineered the format (Luma only for now), at least for some video widths.
I don't know (yet) how chroma samples are laid out however, and the code below is still buggy.

```
void CopyOmxPicture( decoder_t *p_dec, picture_t *p_pic,
                 OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE *p_header, int i_slice_height )
{
decoder_sys_t *p_sys = p_dec->p_sys;
int i_src_stride;
int i_plane, i_width, i_line;
uint8_t *p_dst, *p_src, *p_dst2;

i_src_stride  = p_sys->out.i_frame_stride;
p_src = p_header->pBuffer + p_header->nOffset;

if( p_dec->p_sys->out.definition.format.video.eColorFormat == QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka )
{
    uint8_t *to = p_pic->p[0].p_pixels;
    int w = p_pic->p[0].i_visible_pitch;
    int h = p_pic->p[0].i_visible_lines;
    int pitch = p_pic->p[0].i_pitch;

    msg_Dbg(p_dec, "stride %d pitch %d w %d h %d", i_src_stride, pitch, w, h);

    //copy luma plane
    const int tsz = 64*32;
    int wtiles = (w + 63) / 64; // number of tiles in horizontal direction
    int htiles = (h + 31) / 32; // number of tiles in   vertical direction

    int tile = 0; // FIXME : order differs for other streams

    int tiles_max = 2 * wtiles;
    uint8_t order[tiles_max];
    order[0] = 0;
    order[1] = 1;

    uint8_t done[tiles_max];
    memset(done, 0, tiles_max);
    done[0] = done[1] = 1;

    int j = 2 + 4;
    for (int i = 2; i < tiles_max;) {
        while(done[j]) { j++; j%=tiles_max; }
        done[j] = 1;
        order[i++] = j++; j%= tiles_max;
        while(done[j]) { j++; j%=tiles_max; }
        done[j] = 1;
        order[i++] = j++; j%= tiles_max;
        if (j == 0)
            continue;
        if (i == tiles_max)
            break;
        while(done[j]) { j++; j%=tiles_max; }
        done[j] = 1;
        order[i++] = j++; j%= tiles_max;
        while(done[j]) { j++; j%=tiles_max; }
        done[j] = 1;
        order[i++] = j++;
        j += 4;
        j%= tiles_max;
    }
#if 0
    static const uint8_t order[] = { 0, 1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    static const uint8_t order[] = { 0, 1,
        6,  7,  8,  9,
        14, 15, 16, 17,
        22, 23, 24, 25,
        2,  3,  4,  5 ,
        10, 11, 12, 13,
        18, 19, 20, 21,
        26, 27,
    };
#endif
    i_src_stride += 127; i_src_stride &= ~127;
    //int width_align = tsz * (wtiles & 1); // width is aligned on 128 pixels
    int width_align = i_src_stride - ((wtiles + 1) & ~1) * 64;
    int soff = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < htiles; i++) { // top to bottom
        int lines = 32;
        if ((i == htiles - 1) && (h & 31))
            lines = h & 31;
        for (int j = 0; j < wtiles; j++) { // left to right
            //copy one tile
            int tile_pitch = 64;
            if ((j == wtiles-1) && (w & 63))
                tile_pitch = w & 63;
            int doff = pitch * i * 32 + j * 64;
            for (int l = 0; l < lines; l++) {
                memcpy(&to[doff + l * pitch],
                    &p_src[soff + 64 * 32 * order[tile % tiles_max] + l * 64],
                    tile_pitch);
            }
            if ((++tile % tiles_max) == 0) {
                soff += tiles_max * 64 * 32;
            }
        }
        p_src += width_align;
    }

    // black out chroma
    for (int i = 1; i < p_pic->i_planes; i++)
        memset(p_pic->p[i].p_pixels, 0x80,
                p_pic->p[i].i_pitch * p_pic->p[i].i_visible_lines);

#if 1 //dump
char mask[32];
static int x = 0;
sprintf(mask, "/sdcard/yuv/out%dx%dxp%d-%.3d.yuv", w, h, pitch, ++x);
if ((x & 15) == 0) {
    FILE *f = fopen(mask, "w");
    if ((f = fopen(mask, "w"))) {
#if 1
        //int w = (p_pic->format.i_width + 127) & ~127;
        //int h = (p_pic->format.i_height + 31) & ~31;
        //size_t s = (w * h + 8191) & ~8191;
        size_t s = p_header->nFilledLen;
        fwrite(p_src, s, 1, f);
#else
        fwrite(to, pitch*h*3 / 2, 1, f);
#endif
        fclose(f);
    }
}
#endif

}
}
```