# QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka converter

Tags: android, converters, yuv, stagefright, openmax

I need to handle `YUV` data from H/W decoding output on Android.

Actually, I'm using Nexus4 and the decoding output format is `QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka` type.

But I need `YUV420 Planar` format data, it need to be converted.

Could you share the converting function or any way?

Comment: Potential duplicate: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059738/qomx-color-formatyuv420packedsemiplanar64x32tile2m8ka-color-format 

Also, please refer to this implementation which should help you: www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/modules/codec/omxil/qcom.c

Comment: Do you have any further queries on this topic?