# QCom Decoder Output YUV Buffer Distrubed

Tags: android, video-processing, decoder, stagefright

I'm trying to get images from HD Live Stream. Getting OMX Decoder YUV Streams and converting them into JPG. JPEG is completely disturbed. Tried some suggestions from group but not working. 
My resolution is 320x240.

i will get buffer length is (386 * 256 * 1.5) for configured 320 * 240 resolution. I'm not getting how to get this new width and height information.

JPG conversion code i have in Java and using OMXCodec is in Native. Please help me.

```
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    final int qFrameSize = frameSize/4;
    int padding = 0;/*(width*height + 2047) & ~2047;

    if ((width % 32) != 0) {
        padding = (width*height) % 1024;
    } else {
        padding = (width*height) % 2048;
    }

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize); // Y

    for (int i = 0; i < qFrameSize; i++) {
        output[frameSize + i*2 + padding] = input[frameSize + i + qFrameSize ]; // Cb (U)
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1 + padding] = input[frameSize + i ]; // Cr (V)
    }      
    return ;
}
```

thank you,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

The output of QCom video decoder is usually a specific custom color format which is typically known as **tiled format**. Please refer to these questions which have more inputs on how to convert the data to a more cleaner frame

[QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797923/qomx-color-formatyuv420packedsemiplanar64x32tile2m8ka-converter)

[QOMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka color format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059738/qomx-color-formatyuv420packedsemiplanar64x32tile2m8ka-color-format)