# Converting specialized NV12 video frames to RGB

Tags: android, bitmap, rgb, android-mediacodec

I have an H264 stream that's decoded using an Android MediaCodec. When I query the output MediaFormat, the color format is 2141391875. Apparently, that's a specialized NV12 variant known as HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_NV12_ADRENO_TILED. This is on a Nexus 7 (2013).

I want to take this data and convert it to RGB so I can create a Bitmap. I've found StackOverflow posts for converting other formats to RGB, not this format. I've tried code from those other posts, the result is just streaks of color. (To view the Bitmap, I draw on the Canvas associated with a Surface, as well as write it out as a JPEG -- it looks the same in both cases.)

How can I convert this particular data to RGB?

Comment: Please check this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059738/qomx-color-formatyuv420packedsemiplanar64x32tile2m8ka-color-format . There is one convertor available at www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/modules/codec/omxil/qcom.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2141391875 decimal is 0x7FA30C03 in hex, which according to [this header file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/include/media/openmax/OMX_IVCommon.h) is `OMX_QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka`. Which amounts to the same thing as the constant you found: this is a proprietary Qualcomm color format.

The easiest (and fastest) way to convert it is to let OpenGL ES do the work for you. See for example [ExtractMpegFramesTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest), which decodes video frames to a SurfaceTexture, renders the texture to an off-screen surface, and then reads the pixels out with `glReadPixels()`. The GLES driver will handle the RGB conversion for you.

If you want to do the conversion yourself, you will need to reverse-engineer the color format, or find someone who has done so already and is willing to share.

Comment: There's code at https://gitorious.org/atrix-aosp/frameworks_base/source/8f901240ab7c98ad48542b99342d02ed84937395:media/libstagefright/colorconversion/ColorConverter.cpp and http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=modules/codec/omxil/qcom.c which show how to interpret this format.

Comment: In ExtractMpegFramesTest, the code configures a codec with the Surface obtained from an OutputSurface. Then, when you release an output buffer, you give "true" as the render argument. But suppose I want to use a different rendering mechanism. I configure my codec without a Surface, so in my output buffer, I have the data that results from decoding the input. The format of that data apparently varies according to the hardware. I'd like to render that data to a Surface, but not one passed to MediaCodec::configure(), or use some other way to get pixels to the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at EncodeDecodeTest, not ExtractMpegFramesTest, which may well do what I want.

Comment: See also Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), which does some things with camera input, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: In ExtractMpegFramesTest, there's a SurfaceTexture with an associated Surface, and the code uses OpenGL ES to write to the SurfaceTexture. That approach gives the ability to use glReadPixel, and eventually to save the frame to an image file. If all I want to do is render the frame to the screen, is there any advantage of OpenGL ES over creating a Surface in a SurfaceView? Looking at MediaCodec.java, it looks like it uses native code called SoftwareRenderer in that case.

Comment: The internal name for SurfaceTexture is "GL Consumer". Surfaces are queues of buffers with a producer-consumer relationship; SurfaceTexture is an instance of a consumer that takes each graphics buffer and converts it to a GLES texture. If you're going to use SurfaceTexture, then GLES is the most natural choice for rendering. There is no "software-only buffer consumer" for a Surface. If all you want to do is render to the screen, just send the MediaCodec decoder output to a SurfaceView or TextureView (see Grafika's video players for examples). For fancier stuff, see e.g. "texture from camera".

Comment: (See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html for the full story.)

Comment: Right, my question boils down to whether there's a performance (or other) difference using a SurfaceTexture or the Surface available from a SurfaceView created via a layout. I think you're suggesting there isn't. Thanks I've read that excellent documentation.

Comment: MediaCodec to SurfaceView surface is the most efficient path -- should be zero-copy. For DRM-protected content, this is the only possible path. MediaCodec to SurfaceTexture then render with GLES on a SurfaceView surface adds a YUV-to-RGB conversion, and possibly a scaling blit, which makes it slower but also allows a lot more flexibility in how each frame is rendered. If all you want to do is play video, you should send it straight to a SurfaceView.