# Incorrect image converting YUV_420_888 into Bitmaps under Android camera2

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera2, yuv

I’m trying to convert YUV_420_888 images into bitmaps, coming from the camera2 preview. But the output image has incorrect colors.

Next is the test code I’m running to generate the bitmap. Is test code only, so please don’t do any code review about not relevant factors such as the bitmap is being recycled, or the RenderScript is continuously been created. This code is just to test the conversion from YUV to RGB and nothing more.

Other factors, the code is meant to run from API 22 and above, therefore using RenderScript specific **ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB** should be sufficient, without having to use old manual conversions which where necessary only in previous Android versions due to lack of proper YUV_420_888 support.

As RenderScript already offers a dedicated ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB which is meant to handle all types of YUV conversions, I think the problem could be in how I get the YUV byte data from the Image object, but I can't figure where the issue is.

To view the output bitmap in Android Studio, place a breakpoint in bitmap.recycle(), so before it gets recycled you can look at it in the Variables Debug Window by using the “view bitmap” option.

Please let me know if anyone can spot what’s wrong with the conversion:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
{
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this.mContext);

    final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

    final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    final ByteBuffer planeY = planes[0].getBuffer();
    final ByteBuffer planeU = planes[1].getBuffer();
    final ByteBuffer planeV = planes[2].getBuffer();

    // Get the YUV planes data

    final int Yb = planeY.rewind().remaining();
    final int Ub = planeU.rewind().remaining();
    final int Vb = planeV.rewind().remaining();

    final ByteBuffer yuvData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Yb + Ub + Vb);

    planeY.get(yuvData.array(), 0, Yb);
    planeU.get(yuvData.array(), Yb, Vb);
    planeV.get(yuvData.array(), Yb + Vb, Ub);

    // Initialize Renderscript

    Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs))
            .setX(image.getWidth())
            .setY(image.getHeight())
            .setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);

    final Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs))
            .setX(image.getWidth())
            .setY(image.getHeight());

    Allocation yuvAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    Allocation rgbAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

    // Convert

    yuvAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(yuvData.array());

    ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.YUV(rs));
    scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(yuvAllocation);
    scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(rgbAllocation);

    // Get the bitmap

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    rgbAllocation.copyTo(bitmap);

    // Release

    bitmap.recycle();

    yuvAllocation.destroy();
    rgbAllocation.destroy();
    rs.destroy();

    image.close();
}
```

Comment: It is not guaranteed, but usually the U and V planes will overlap. YUV_420_888 is a wrapper that can host, or example, NV21 images. In this case, length of planeU and of planeV buffers will be twice their actual size. Code that converts any YUV_420_888 to Bitmap using Renderscript can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212904/yuv-420-888-interpretation-on-samsung-galaxy-s7-camera2).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the hint. I've updated the question to more clearly specify that should use the existing ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB instead of using alternatives that imply to create new YUV conversion scripts. Thanks

Comment: I respect your preference to use **ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB**, but please understand that using a custom Renderscript is not less efficient.

Comment: By the way, **ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB** is wrong for camera frames, because these functions use the *video* [BT.610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion) color space (where **Y** is in range `[16…235]`).

Comment: The code for converting YUV to RGB works nicely. But I found that to convert from YUV420P, you need to use YV12 instead of YUV_420_888.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, the actual problem was as I suspected in how I was transforming the Image planes into the ByteBuffer. Next the solution, which should work for both NV21 & YV12. As the YUV data already comes in separate planes, is just a matter of getting it the correct way based on their row and pixel strides. Also needed to do some minor modifications in how the data is passed to the RenderScript intrinsic.

NOTE: For a production optimized onImageAvailable() uninterrupted flow, instead, before doing the conversion the Image byte data should be copied into a separate buffer and the conversion executed in a separate thread (depending on your requirements). But since this isn't part of the question, in the next code the conversion is placed directly into onImageAvailable() to simplify the answer. If anyone needs to know how to copy the Image data please create a new question and let me know so I will share my code.

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader)
{
    // Get the YUV data

    final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    final ByteBuffer yuvBytes = this.imageToByteBuffer(image);

    // Convert YUV to RGB

    final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this.mContext);

    final Bitmap        bitmap     = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Allocation allocationRgb = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);

    final Allocation allocationYuv = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.U8(rs), yuvBytes.array().length);
    allocationYuv.copyFrom(yuvBytes.array());

    ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(allocationYuv);
    scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(allocationRgb);

    allocationRgb.copyTo(bitmap);

    // Release

    bitmap.recycle();

    allocationYuv.destroy();
    allocationRgb.destroy();
    rs.destroy();

    image.close();
}

private ByteBuffer imageToByteBuffer(final Image image)
{
    final Rect crop   = image.getCropRect();
    final int  width  = crop.width();
    final int  height = crop.height();

    final Image.Plane[] planes     = image.getPlanes();
    final byte[]        rowData    = new byte[planes[0].getRowStride()];
    final int           bufferSize = width * height * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888) / 8;
    final ByteBuffer    output     = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);

    int channelOffset = 0;
    int outputStride = 0;

    for (int planeIndex = 0; planeIndex < 3; planeIndex++)
    {
        if (planeIndex == 0)
        {
            channelOffset = 0;
            outputStride = 1;
        }
        else if (planeIndex == 1)
        {
            channelOffset = width * height + 1;
            outputStride = 2;
        }
        else if (planeIndex == 2)
        {
            channelOffset = width * height;
            outputStride = 2;
        }

        final ByteBuffer buffer      = planes[planeIndex].getBuffer();
        final int        rowStride   = planes[planeIndex].getRowStride();
        final int        pixelStride = planes[planeIndex].getPixelStride();

        final int shift         = (planeIndex == 0) ? 0 : 1;
        final int widthShifted  = width >> shift;
        final int heightShifted = height >> shift;

        buffer.position(rowStride * (crop.top >> shift) + pixelStride * (crop.left >> shift));

        for (int row = 0; row < heightShifted; row++)
        {
            final int length;

            if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1)
            {
                length = widthShifted;
                buffer.get(output.array(), channelOffset, length);
                channelOffset += length;
            }
            else
            {
                length = (widthShifted - 1) * pixelStride + 1;
                buffer.get(rowData, 0, length);

                for (int col = 0; col < widthShifted; col++)
                {
                    output.array()[channelOffset] = rowData[col * pixelStride];
                    channelOffset += outputStride;
                }
            }

            if (row < heightShifted - 1)
            {
                buffer.position(buffer.position() + rowStride - length);
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this method introduces significant overhead. By the nature of DirectByteBuffer that comes from the camera, pixel by pixel copy is much more efficient if written as Java native method (using JNI). But more importantly, if you can identify your input as NV21 or YV12, you can copy it in one step, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/multi-stage-post-processing-renderscript-for-android-on-intel-architecture

Comment: Absolutely agree. There is an overhead, and the sample code I’ve supplied in my answer isn’t meant or optimized for production, but instead only for testing. A proper implementation, if following my solution, would be to copy the Image planes data in a separate buffer, probably a FIFO one, then let the camera image callback to proceed with the preview, and perform the actual conversion/processing in a background thread, and not as in the workflow in my sample code.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot agree with your remarks. Live preview is independent from **onImageAvailable()**. Also, **camera2** already put your callbacks on a background thread, so there is no need to introduce another one. If your processing is slower than the frame rate, I would rather drop the older frames to catch up, instead of FIFO.

Comment: The objective for my requirement is to record GIF animations from the camera preview. To achieve good performance, though not explained in my solution as isn't part of the question, I've set the preview to copy the Planes ByteBuffers into a FIFO, and then in a background thread pick up the frames as they arrive, perform the YUV/Bitmap transform, and feed the result into our GIF encoder, all while the preview is running. This way when the max amount of frames are finally obtained, we have a large number already encoded, plus the memory isn’t completely filled up with pending frames.

Comment: Well OK, in my experiments there was never much space to keep 'pending frames'. You probably don't need maximum resolution to produce GIF.

Comment: @PerracoLabs I got this exception  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Crop rect is unknown in this image. any idea why this line final Rect crop   = image.getCropRect(); throws the exception.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Create a new question, and post to it the full stacktrace for a very understanding the issue. I had a look into the source code of the getCropRect() method in the Image class, and the only exception it can throw is an IllegalStateException if the Image object is already closed. Couldn't find any reference to an UnsupportedOperationException. Although maybe such exception was thrown in a previous version of Android. So specify also in the question your testing android version.

Comment: @PerracoLabs but I got this exception when I use this with ARCore. It will throw above exception. I also put the delay while final Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage(); call this function because continuous access this function every second throw exception of resource exhausted. Any idea why I throw this exception.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper It would be better if you post a new question with the full exception stacktrace to see who is triggering it. About the resources exhausted exception, you need to catch/manage it. When calling ImageReader.newInstance, the last parameter defines the max amount of Images available before the ImageReader stalls. Therefore each Image object must be closed as soon as done with it, so it can be reused by the ImageReader. Don't be tempted to define a large a mount of Image objects, as you will run out of memory quick, since these will accumulate into memory if not processed in time.

Comment: @PerracoLabs here is the link where I put the question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69718817/5860777

Answer (score 2):

RenderScript support YUV_420_888 as ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB's source

1. create Allocation & ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB

   ```
   RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
   ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB mScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(renderScript, Element.YUV(renderScript));
   Allocation mAllocationInYUV = Allocation.createTyped(renderScript, new Type.Builder(renderScript, Element.YUV(renderScript)).setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888).setX(480).setY(640).create(), Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
   Allocation mAllocationOutRGB = Allocation.createTyped(renderScript, Type.createXY(renderScript, Element.RGBA_8888(renderScript), 480, 640), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT | Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT);
   ```
2. set Allocation.getSurface() to receive image data from camera

   ```
   final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequest = session.getDevice().createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
   captureRequest.addTarget(mAllocationInYUV.getSurface());
   ```
3. output to a TextureView or ImageReader or SurfaceView

   ```
   mAllocationOutRGB.setSurface(new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
   mAllocationInYUV.setOnBufferAvailableListener(new Allocation.OnBufferAvailableListener() {
       @Override
       public void onBufferAvailable(Allocation a) {
           a.ioReceive();
           mScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.setInput(a);
           mScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.forEach(mAllocationOutRGB);
           mAllocationOutRGB.ioSend();
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to copy a YUV_420_888 camera frame in into an RS Allocation. Actually, as of today, Renderscript [does not support this format](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/4bcc2cf8f68f80bed9815549f73af4720f9322d2/cpp/Type.cpp#218).

If you know that, under the hood, your frame is NV21 or YV12 - you can copy the entire ByteBuffer to an array and pass it to RS Allocation.